# Passing global as a reference

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I have a situation similar to this:

```
x = 10
y = 20
z = 30

def check_x():
 global x
 if something:
    x = x + 10

def check_y():
 global y
 if something:
    y = y + 15

def check_z():
 global z
 if something:
    z = z + 20
```

How can I achieve to refactor in order to have a situation lik this:

```
x = 10
y = 20
z = 30

def check(var, adding):
     global ??
     if something:
        ?? = ?? + adding


check(x, 10)
check(y, 15)
check(z, 20)
```

Basically, I can't refer to a given global variable in the general function.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) dict, and pass a str as argument:

```
>>> x = 10

>>> def check_x(glb, adding):
        if glb in globals():
            globals()[glb] += adding

>>> check_x('x', 10)
>>> x
20
```